# Remove An Element When One Exists

Tags: javascript

I'm back with my nooby Javascript questions. I'm working on form validation and I'm adding text to check if a name was inputted. The problem I'm running into is if I don't put a name but then I do, the message for not putting a name shows up with the other element and vice versa but im looking for a way to make it dissapear when another element is chosen. Is there some sort of way of preventing an element from showing when one is present? I appreciate you guys/girls taking time out of your day to help a noob out haha. :)

Code:

```js
var complete = document.getElementById('button');

complete.addEventListener('click', validate);

function validate() {

  var textBox = document.getElementById('name');
  var red = document.getElementById('nah');
  var green = document.getElementById('yah');

  if (textBox.value === '') {
    red.style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    green.style.display = 'block';
  }
}
```

```css
#nah {
  display: none;
  color: red;
}

#yah {
  color: green;
  display: none;
}

button {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 50px;
  border: 0.1px solid red;
  background: red;
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="name">

<p id="nah">Please Enter Name!</p>
<p id="yah">Thank you!</p>

<button id="button">Complete Form</button>
```

Comment: You need to remember to hide the red div upon validation (display: none)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you show one message you need to hide the other one.

```js
var complete = document.getElementById('button');

complete.addEventListener('click', validate);

function validate() {

  var textBox = document.getElementById('name');
  var red = document.getElementById('nah');
  var green = document.getElementById('yah');

  if (textBox.value === '') {
    red.style.display = 'block';
    green.style.display = 'none';
  } else {
    green.style.display = 'block';
    red.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```css
#nah {
  display: none;
  color: red;
}

#yah {
  color: green;
  display: none;
}

button {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 50px;
  border: 0.1px solid red;
  background: red;
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="name">

<p id="nah">Please Enter Name!</p>
<p id="yah">Thank you!</p>

<button id="button">Complete Form</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Simplest way is to just hide the other messages during validation:

```
function validate() {

  var textBox = document.getElementById('name');
  var red = document.getElementById('nah');
  var green = document.getElementById('yah');

  if (textBox.value === '') {
    red.style.display = 'block';
    green.style.display = 'none';   //hide the other element
  } else {
    green.style.display = 'block';
    red.style.display = 'none';   //hide the other element
  }
}
```

You could do it in a more sophisticated way using data attributes to control visibility, but this is probably a good start.

Comment: You could have a container element with a custom attribute called `data-valid`, like this: `<div id="container" data-valid="true"></div>` and then use CSS selectors to switch visibility: `#container[data-valid='true'] .green-message { display: block; }`